# Twitter Bootstrap individual navbar menu item colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar menu in Bootstrap like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Change Color of this Menu Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to change the color of the final list item so it does not inherit the standard color/hover properties. Is it possible to target just the final menu item via CSS and override my Bootstraps CSS?

My CSS here:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Fjalla One", sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
   color: #0091c1;
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use last-child

```
.navbar-nav li:last-child {
    background: red;
}
```

see this js-fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2690/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with the `:last-child` pseudo selector, like this:

```css
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: blue;
}
.navbar-nav > li:last-child > a {
    color: green;  
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Change Color of this Menu Item</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:not(:last-child) > a
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/rm4wqua7/

it will not give styles for `:last-child`

or owerite styles for `:last-child` child

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:last-child > a
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/rm4wqua7/1/