# Changing color of twitter bootstrap nav bar item

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I don't have much experience with web. Firstly I refered to this post here but can't get it to work in my case. [changing last item color if navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581374/twitter-bootstrap-individual-navbar-menu-item-colors)

I am trying to change the color of each navbar menu item to red but can't get it to work. Secondly if I want a separate style for the a href item where id="active". How can I refer to that particular item in my css. Please help.

Here is my body.

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-3">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">

<a href="" class="navbar-brand">KGS</a>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="target">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#" id="active" class="nav-link">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
<a href="#" class="nav-link">Our Clients</a>
</li>
   
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
    
</body>
```

Now in the default1.css, I am doing something like this. However when I hover over an item I can see the blue color. Likewise I want each nav bar item to be in red color, but I can't get it to work. Please help.

```
.navbar-nav > li > a{
        color:red;
    }
    
        .navbar-nav > li:hover a{
        background: blue;
        border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
        color: #2056ac;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the text or the background color of the navbar item?

Comment: I want to change the color of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap comes with some predefined styles, so in order to override them, an easy way is to use the keyword `!important` in your css. If you omit this keyword it is unlikely that you will see a color change in your case due to Bootstrap's default styling, therefore I recommend you add it.

**CSS**

```
.nav-link, .navbar-brand{
    color: red!important;
}

#active{
    color: blue!important;
}
```

See codeply: https://www.codeply.com/p/pLDEIidtkA

Comment: @nikhil Do you require any more assistance?

Comment: No thank you so much. That should be all. I will post a new question and tag you in case if I need help.

Comment: Can you please help me with this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309894/bootstrap-unordered-list-with-bullets