# bootstrap unordered list with bullets

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

How do I show the bullets for an unorderlist in bootstrap. I have the following html

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            Do you need a research on your particuar ancestor or your goal is to make a family tree?
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">Do you want to know how home of your ancestor looked like, if it's still there? We will provide photos!</li>
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">Do you need to obtain a specific record (birth, marriage, death certificates, Census, tax, property ownership, etc)? </li>
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">Do you want to find and visit your ancestral town and talk with locals to hear some family lores about your ancestors?</li>
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">Do you need to find a grave, house or plot where your ancestors lived?</li>
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">Do you need a guide through local archives or repositories while doing your research in Eastern Europe? </li>
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">Do you want to find a living relative or missing heir for an estate?</li>
            <li class="list-group-item border-0">Do you need a priceless gift for your parents, relatives or colleagues?  </li>
            </ul>    
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In my default1.css I am doing the following but it doesn't show the bullets. Please help.

```
.list-group-item border-0 {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo. border-0 needs a period in front of it to specify it as a class selector instead of an element selector like this:

```
.list-group-item .border-0 {
  list-style-type: disc !important;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

Secondly, you don't need to be that specific with this amount of code. All you need is `list-group-item`. Try this:

```
.list-group-item::before {
  content: "●";
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
}
```

`::before` is a pseudo element that you can use to put content before an element, but you have to give it content with the `content: "●"` property.